# Finding first success amongst Promise returning functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, short-circuiting

Given some number of functions, returning promises:

```
function foo(arg) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (stuff(arg)) {
      resolve('result from foo');
    } else {
      resolve(null);
    }
  });
);

// ... maybe more of these functions ...

function bar(arg) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (otherStuff(arg)) {
      resolve('result from bar');
    } else {
      resolve(null);
    }
  });
);
```

**How can we iterate through the functions in a serial fashion, short circuiting after the first function returning a non-null value?**

```
[
  foo,
  // ...
  bar
].firstWithArg('some arg')
  .then(function(result) {
    // result: 'result from ___', or `null`
  });
```

Essentially, the desired behaviour is:

```
new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
  foo('some-arg')
    .then(function(result) {
      if (result) {
        resolve(result);
      } else {

        // ...

          bar('some-arg')
            .then(function(result) {
              if (result) {
                resolve(result);
              } else {
                resolve(null); // no functions left
              }
            })
      }
    });
});
```

**Promise.race() can't be used, as the functions can't all be fired. They must be executed serially, stopping after the first success.**

Comment: Ask **one** question per question. Your questions above have quite different use cases and solutions, and your first question has nothing to do with your question title.

Comment: [`Promise.race()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I really included the first question as an analogy for the second.

Comment: @jfriend00 I looked at Promise.race(), but it doesn't fit my use case. I need to execute the functions serially, and short-circuit, not fire all of them and get the result of the first to finish.

Comment: @bosticko: That isn't remotely clear above. I suggest clarifying it.

Comment: Why would you have your second example functions `resolve(null)` rather than `reject()`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Because no error occurred. `resolve(value)` means that a resource was found, and used. `resolve(null)` means that nothing went wrong, but no resource was found, so the next function should be called to look for the next resource type.

Comment: @bosticko: Fair enough, glad I covered both options in my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120855/discussion-between-bosticko-and-t-j-crowder).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've said your first question is really just setup for the second, which is the real question.

So I think your question is: How do you execute a series of functions that return promises serially, short-circuiting when the first one resolves with a non-`null` value?

I probably wouldn't, I'd use *`reject`* rather than `resolve(null)` (but in a comment you've clarified you want `resolve(null)`, and I see your point; I cover that below):

```
function foo(arg) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (stuff(arg)) {
      resolve('result from foo');
    } else {
      reject();          // <=== Note
    }
  });
}

// ... maybe more of these functions ...

function bar(arg) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (otherStuff(arg)) {
      resolve('result from bar');
    } else {
      reject();          // <=== Note
    }
  });
}
```

Then you use `catch` to handle rejections up until you get back a resolution:

```
foo("a")
  .catch(() => bar(1))
  .catch(() => foo("b"))
  .catch(() => bar(2))
  .catch(() => foo("c"))
  .catch(() => bar(3))
  .then(value => {
    console.log("Done", value);
  });
```

```js
function otherStuff(arg) {
  return arg == 2;
}

function stuff(arg) {
  return arg == "c";
}

function foo(arg) {
  console.log("foo:", arg);
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (stuff(arg)) {
      console.log("foo:", arg, "resolving");
      resolve('result from foo');
    } else {
      console.log("foo:", arg, "rejecting");
      reject(); // <=== Note
    }
  });
}

// ... maybe more of these functions ...

function bar(arg) {
  console.log("bar:", arg);
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (otherStuff(arg)) {
      console.log("bar:", arg, "resolving");
      resolve('result from bar');
    } else {
      console.log("bar:", arg, "rejecting");
      reject(); // <=== Note
    }
  });
}

foo("a")
  .catch(() => bar(1))
  .catch(() => foo("b"))
  .catch(() => bar(2))
  .catch(() => foo("c"))
  .catch(() => bar(3))
  .then(value => {
    console.log("Done", value);
  });
```

That works because resolutions bypass the `catch` handlers, so the subsequent functions are never called.

If you have an array of functions to call, there's an idiom for it: `Array#reduce`:

```
let functions = [
  () => foo("a"),
  () => bar(1),
  () => foo("b"),
  () => bar(2),
  () => foo("c"),
  () => bar(3)
];

functions.reduce((p, fn) => p.catch(fn), Promise.reject())
  .then(value => {
    console.log("Done", value);
  });
```

```js
function otherStuff(arg) {
  return arg == 2;
}

function stuff(arg) {
  return arg == "c";
}

function foo(arg) {
  console.log("foo:", arg);
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (stuff(arg)) {
      console.log("foo:", arg, "resolving");
      resolve('result from foo');
    } else {
      console.log("foo:", arg, "rejecting");
      reject(); // <=== Note
    }
  });
}

// ... maybe more of these functions ...

function bar(arg) {
  console.log("bar:", arg);
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (otherStuff(arg)) {
      console.log("bar:", arg, "resolving");
      resolve('result from bar');
    } else {
      console.log("bar:", arg, "rejecting");
      reject(); // <=== Note
    }
  });
}

let functions = [
  () => foo("a"),
  () => bar(1),
  () => foo("b"),
  () => bar(2),
  () => foo("c"),
  () => bar(3)
];

functions.reduce((p, fn) => p.catch(fn), Promise.reject())
  .then(value => {
    console.log("Done", value);
  });
```

As you probably know, `Array#reduce` is useful for "reducing" an array to a value, such as with a simple sum:

```
[1, 2, 3].reduce((sum, value) => sum + value, 0); // 6
```

In the above, for the "sum" equivalent, we start with a rejected promise and use `catch` to create the chain of promises. The result of calling `reduce` is the last promise from `catch`.

---

**But**, if you want to use `resolve(null)` instead, you use `then` in a similar way:

```
foo("a")
  .then(result => result ? result : bar(1))
  .then(result => result ? result : foo("b"))
  .then(result => result ? result : bar(2))
  .then(result => result ? result : foo("d"))
  .then(result => result ? result : bar(3))
  .then(value => {
    console.log("Done", value);
  });
```

```js
function otherStuff(arg) {
  return arg == 2;
}

function stuff(arg) {
  return arg == "c";
}

function foo(arg) {
  console.log("foo:", arg);
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (stuff(arg)) {
      console.log("foo:", arg, "resolving");
      resolve('result from foo');
    } else {
      console.log("foo:", arg, "resolving null");
      resolve(null);
    }
  });
}

// ... maybe more of these functions ...

function bar(arg) {
  console.log("bar:", arg);
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (otherStuff(arg)) {
      console.log("bar:", arg, "resolving");
      resolve('result from bar');
    } else {
      console.log("bar:", arg, "resolving null");
      resolve(null);
    }
  });
}

foo("a")
  .then(result => result ? result : bar(1))
  .then(result => result ? result : foo("b"))
  .then(result => result ? result : bar(2))
  .then(result => result ? result : foo("d"))
  .then(result => result ? result : bar(3))
  .then(value => {
    console.log("Done", value);
  });
```

Or with an array:

```
let functions = [
  () => foo("a"),
  () => bar(1),
  () => foo("b"),
  () => bar(2),
  () => foo("c"),
  () => bar(3)
];

functions.reduce((p, fn) => p.then(result => result ? result : fn()), Promise.resolve(null))
  .then(value => {
    console.log("Done", value);
  });
```

```js
function otherStuff(arg) {
  return arg == 2;
}

function stuff(arg) {
  return arg == "c";
}

function foo(arg) {
  console.log("foo:", arg);
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (stuff(arg)) {
      console.log("foo:", arg, "resolving");
      resolve('result from foo');
    } else {
      console.log("foo:", arg, "resolving null");
      resolve(null);
    }
  });
}

// ... maybe more of these functions ...

function bar(arg) {
  console.log("bar:", arg);
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (otherStuff(arg)) {
      console.log("bar:", arg, "resolving");
      resolve('result from bar');
    } else {
      console.log("bar:", arg, "resolving null");
      resolve(null);
    }
  });
}

let functions = [
  () => foo("a"),
  () => bar(1),
  () => foo("b"),
  () => bar(2),
  () => foo("c"),
  () => bar(3)
];
    
functions.reduce((p, fn) => p.then(result => result ? result : fn()), Promise.resolve(null))
  .then(value => {
    console.log("Done", value);
  });
```

That works because if we get back a truthy value (or you could use `result => result !== null ? result : nextCall()`), we return that result down the chain, which means that that `then` returns a resolved promise with that value; but if we get back a falsy value, we call the next function and return its promise.

As you can see, this is a bit more verbose, which is part of why promises have this distinction between resolution and rejection.

Comment: Is there a way to programmatically chain the calls though, if there were some large number of functions?

Comment: @bosticko - Yes, in my answer which you haven't seemed to pay any attention to.

Comment: @bosticko: Do you mean if you had an array of functions to call?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder exactly, an array of functions.

Comment: @bosticko: Yup. There's even an idiom for it. I've added it to the answer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ahh, I had a feeling reduce would come into play, but I didn't know how to integrate it.
Last thing: Each of those functions should be passed the same arguments. (`[() => foo(arg), () => bar(arg)]`) What would be the best way to express that, rather than entering them manually?

Comment: @bosticko: I'd have to see a real example, but for instance in the above where I create the array of functions, you could use a variable those arrow functions close over to pass them args. `let args = ['a', 1]; let functions = [() => foo(...args), ...];`

Comment: The use case is an identifier for a resource comes in for processing. It is passed to a function which treats it as a certain type, and does some processing, if it can. If it can't, we fallback to a different function, which will treat it as a different resource type, and try some similar, but different processing, if it can. This continues, falling back through some number of functions, until the resource is either found and processed, or we determine the identifier was bad.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's anything prebuilt for this.  You can create your own without too much work.  Supposed you have an array of functions that return promises when called.  You can then iterate through that array and stop when you get a result you like.  It wasn't clear what you wanted to do when a promise in the sequence rejects - this implementation continues onto the next function, but you can code whatever behavior you want for that situation:

```
function iterateUntilGood(list, args) {
    var cntr = 0;

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        function next() {
            if (list.length > cntr) {
                list[cntr++].apply(null, args).then(function(result) {
                    // check the result here
                    if (some condition) {
                        resolve(result);
                    } else {
                        next();
                    }
                }, next);
            } else {
                reject("No function succeeded");
            }
        }
        next();
    });
}

// usage
iterateUntilGood([fn1, fn2, fn3, fn4], [arg1, arg2]).then(function(result) {
    // got result here
}, function(err) {
    // handle error here
});
```

Working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/fwr03f7q/

Comment: So you're recursively iterating through the list of functions, until you find the desired result?

Comment: @bosticko - Yes, pretty much.  It's not regular recursion because there's no stack build-up since these are async operations.  But, it is using a common function to execute the next step in the iteration until you find a result you like and want to stop the iteration.  This is a common pattern for serializing async operations.  You execute the next async operation in the completion of the prior one.

Comment: @bosticko - I added arguments for the functions in the array to my solution.

Comment: It would be good to see this working in a snippet, but I trust you. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I added a jsFiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out thanks to the answers from @T.J.Crowder and @jfriend00.

## TL;DR:

```
const arg = 'some common arg';
const functions = [
  arg => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    /* Does some work, then calls:
     *   resolve(something) if success
     *   resolve(null)      if failure
     *   reject(error)      if error
     */
  })
]

functions.reduce(
  (prev, fn) => prev.then(res => res ? res : fn(arg)),
  Promise.resolve(null) // base case
) // returns promise which honours same contract as functions
  //   (resolves with something or null, or rejects with error)
```

---

*Objective: Iterate through functions returning Promises, until we successfully `resolve` with a value, after which we short-circuit. We do not want to `Promise.race`, instead  running the functions serially.*

See this snippet for a complete working example:

```js
/* Define functions which return Promises honouring the following contract:
 *   switch (state) {
 *     case success:
 *       resolve(result);
 *       break;
 *     case failure:
 *       resolve(null);
 *       break;
 *     case error:
 *       reject(error);
 *   }
 */
const functions = [
  arg => new Promise((resolve) => {
    console.log('checking a against', arg);
    if (arg === 'a') {
      resolve('A');
    } else {
      resolve();
    }
  }),
  arg => new Promise((resolve) => {
    console.log('checking b against', arg);
    if (arg === 'b') {
      resolve('B');
    } else {
      resolve();
    }
  }),
  // Intentionally omit handling 'c'
  arg => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('checking d against', arg);
    if (arg === 'd') {
      console.log('simulating error');
      reject(new Error('D'));
    } else {
      resolve();
    }
  }),
  arg => new Promise((resolve) => {
    console.log('checking e against', arg);
    if (arg === 'e') {
      resolve('E');
    } else {
      resolve();
    }
  })
];

/* Successively call functions with given arg until we resolve a value,
 * after which we short-circuit.
 */
function delegate(arg) {
  console.log('\nDELEGATING for', arg);

  functions.reduce(
      // Note that this null comparison always happens N times,
      // where N is the number of functions
      // (unless one of the functions rejects)
      (p, fn) => p.then(r => r ? r : fn(arg)),
      Promise.resolve(null)
    ).then(value => {
      console.log('Done:', value);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('Error:', error);
    });
}

// Run sample input through the delegate function
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'].forEach(function(e, i) {
  setTimeout(delegate.bind(null, e), i * 100); // delay, for printing
});
```

I've implemented the same example using the suggested `reject(null)` strategy, as opposed to `resolve(null)`, to signify a non-error failure which shouldn't halt iteration through the functions:

```js
/* Define functions which return Promises honouring the following contract:
 *   switch (state) {
 *     case success:
 *       resolve(result);
 *       break;
 *     case failure:
 *       reject(null); // << NOTE
 *       break;
 *     case error:
 *       reject(error);
 *   }
 */
const functions = [
  arg => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('checking a against', arg);
    if (arg === 'a') {
      resolve('A');
    } else {
      reject();
    }
  }),
  arg => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('checking b against', arg);
    if (arg === 'b') {
      resolve('B');
    } else {
      reject();
    }
  }),
  // Intentionally omit handling 'c'
  arg => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('checking d against', arg);
    if (arg === 'd') {
      console.log('simulating error');
      reject(new Error('D'));
    } else {
      reject();
    }
  }),
  arg => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('checking e against', arg);
    if (arg === 'e') {
      resolve('E');
    } else {
      reject();
    }
  })
];
/* Successively call functions with given arg until we resolve a value,
 * after which we short-circuit.
 */
function delegate(arg) {
  console.log('\nDELEGATING for', arg);

  functions.reduce(
      // Check for error, or just rejection without value.
      // Note that this check happens N-1 times,
      // where N is the number of functions until one resolves
      (p, fn) => p.catch(e => e ? Promise.reject(e) : fn(arg)),
      Promise.reject()
    ).then(value => {
      console.log('Done:', value);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('Error:', error);
    });
}

['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'].forEach(function(e, i) {
  setTimeout(delegate.bind(null, e), i * 100); // delay, for printing
});
```

Note, if you read @T.J.Crowder's excellent example, that we must add checking for an error in the `catch` function:

```
(p, fn) => p.catch(e => e ? Promise.reject(e) : fn(arg))
```

If we had just

```
(p, fn) => p.catch(() => fn(arg))
```

or

```
(p, fn) => p.catch(fn.bind(null, arg))
```

we would silently absorb errors (`reject(error)`), and continue as though we had simply encountered a non-error failure.

With this in mind, we do end up with clearer, and slightly more efficient (on average) code by using the `reject(null)` style.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I've adapted your answer into what I was looking for, if you have any feedback. Thanks for your help.